# Can't change text in 'on click' javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a 'if,else' statement in javaScript. I want to change the "h2" text. I think I'm missing some code

```
<div id="game"> 
  <p id="howMany">How many fingers am I holding up?</p> 
  <p id="theGame"> <input type="guess" id="guess" placeholder="0 to 5"> 
    <button id="check-guess"> Guess! </button> 
  </p> 
  <div id="theAnswer"> 
    <h2 id="h2">Your Reward</h2> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

```
document.getElementById("check-guess").onclick = function() {
  var randomNumber = Math.random();
  randomNumber = randomNumber * 6;
  randomNumber = Math.floor(randomNumber);
  if (document.getElementById("guess").value == randomNumber) {
    document.getElementsById("h2").innerHTML = "You got it!";
                         } else {
    document.getElementsById("h2").innerHTML = "Nope! Try Again. The number is " +  randomNumber ;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to add an id to the H2 and reference it that way. You are trying to pass a tag name instead of the id

Comment: simple typo. `getElementsById`

Comment: Fast spot @JasonB!

Comment: @MauroAlmeida yes

Comment: its getElementById not getElementsById

Comment: querySelector('h2') works to.

Comment: @SanjayBisht thanks xD. Didn't see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `getElementsById` doesn't exist, it could be getElementById. The value you pass needs to be an id, not a tagname.

```js
document.getElementById("check-guess").onclick = function() {

  var randomNumber = Math.random();

  randomNumber = randomNumber * 6;

  randomNumber = Math.floor(randomNumber);

  if (document.getElementById("guess").value == randomNumber) {

    document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = "You got it!";

  } else {

    document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = "Nope! Try Again. The number is " + randomNumber;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="guess">
<button id="check-guess">Check</button>
<h2 id="h2">Test</h2>
```